# Referring to Related Record ID In Controller On Save()

Tags: grails, groovy, hashmap, grails-orm

I'm still new to Grails and GORM and I got stumped on this and wasn't able to figure out what I am doing wrong.  The intent is to automatically relate the record to the logged in user through the Shiro plugin for Grails.

```
Class User { static hasMany = [stuff: Stuff] }
Class Stuff { static belongsTo = [user:User] }

Class StuffController {
  def create = {
    params.put('user', User.createCriteria().get{eq('username',SecurityUtils.subject.principal)}.id)            
    def stuffInstance = new Stuff(params)
    stuffInstance.save()
  }
}
```

I saw in the generate-views version of the create scaffold that the relevant field was referred to as name="user.id", but neither it nor variants (such as user_id) seems to work.  The query to the Users domain returns the record id necessary, and params.put in this context seems to correctly append the *params* object with the new value when I render to a test page (so I'm guessing it's not immutable), but this is what I get from the save():

`Property [user] of class [class org.stuffing.Stuff] cannot be null`

I've even tried flipping it around and going the other way, with the same result:

```
User.createCriteria().get{eq('username',SecurityUtils.subject.principal)}
  .addToStuff(new Stuff(params))`
  .save()
```

Anyone able to enlighten me on what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Apparently I was being braindead; I was overriding the "create" method, but the default action is "save" in the _form.gsp template, so it wasn't executing that branch.

On the plus side, I did learn about dynamic finders via Burt below, so it wasn't a total wash.

Thanks for your time, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be a lot cleaner - there's no reason to use createCriteria here. If you're searching by username, use a dynamic finder:

```
def stuffInstance = new Stuff(params)
def user = User.findByUsername(SecurityUtils.subject.principal)
stuffInstance.user = user
if (!stuffInstance.save()) {
   // inspect stuffInstance.errors
}
```

Comment: Apparently I was being braindead; I was overriding the "create" method, but the default action is "save" in the _form.gsp template, so it wasn't executing that branch.

Thanks for the bit about dynamic finders though, that will help! :-)